# No way to upgrade release from 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

When trying to upgrade the release from 18.04, I keep getting the message:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

However, all updates are installed, all third party repos are disabled. There are hundreds of pages out there which give advice about how to fix that problem, nothing works. There is no additional information about what is the problem.

When running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` I am getting this message instead:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Upgrades to the development release are only
> available from the latest supported release.

What I already tried:

```
apt clean 
apt autoclean 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade -y 
sudo apt dist-upgrade 

sudo do-release-upgrade 
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

There are no kept packages, this is not a 32 bit release.

Current system info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Linux pflaume 4.15.0-126-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 23 18:53:38 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

UPDATE after the answer was figured out: to fully investigate this problem check for all these:

- ALL canonical sources are enabled
- NO other sources are enabled
- NO packages are kept (remove those if necessary)
- System is 64 bit
- System is rebooted after any of the above issues was fixed

Comment: Your details highlight a not fully upgraded *bionic* system, as your details say 18.04.5, and a fully upgraded *bionic* system has reported itself as 18.04.6 for some time (https://ubuntu-news.org/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/)  I'd start by checking your sources, and reading the output from commands (starting with `sudo apt update`)

Comment: Add the outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to your question.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc that is important info. Strange that the Ubuntu commands do not seem to know about this ...
I think I might have found the problem: it seems that in the first tab of software-properties-gtk the first source was deselected (!!). No idea why or how that happened but also strange that the Ubuntu commands do not pick up on that to help the user.

Comment: If your sources are correct (ie. no missing lines; why I suggested reading `sudo apt update` output, or reading your sources.list file) normal `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade` (or `apt dist-upgrade`) will cause 18.04.5 to upgrade to 18.04.6 if no packages are held (`apt-mark showhold` will usually show those..)

Comment: @guiverc would you like to add your suggestion as an answer so I can assign it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your details highlight a not fully upgraded bionic system, as your details say 18.04.5, and a fully upgraded bionic system has reported itself as 18.04.6 for some time (https://ubuntu-news.org/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/)

I'd start by checking your sources, and reading the output from commands (starting with `sudo apt update`)

If your sources are correct (ie. *no missing lines; why I suggested reading `sudo apt update` output, or reading your `sources.list` file*) normal `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade` (or `apt dist-upgrade`) will cause 18.04.5 to upgrade to 18.04.6 **if** no packages are held (`apt-mark showhold` will usually show those..)

Comment: Note:  I don't consider this an answer... I'm aware of what current systems report themselves as (*when fully upgraded*) for releases I use, or where I've read Ubuntu ML announcements for fixes/released products etc...  As I'm on the *Ubuntu News* team I see most anyway  (posting the ML post to fridge.ubuntu.com I provided anyway)

Comment: The reason was indeed that sources were missing (not all Canonical sources were enabled in the  software-properties-gtk dialog). For this reason, the system was unable to upgrade to the most recent version of 18.04. However there was no indication given by Ubuntu which made it so hard to figure this out.